# Angular4 compareWith function executing way too many times

Tags: angular

I made a model driven form, with three formControls inside. two of them are initialized by `null`, and the last one is initialized with an object.

The values will change using a `<select>` tag of 50 items. The value will be of type `Object`. Internet told me that in case of an object value, I should use `[compareWith]` function, so i do.

[actually, angular told me (see option caveat)](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)

The first 2 ( initialized on `null` ) execute the compareWith function 50 times, as it should because there are 50 items to compare with.

The last (initialized with an object) executes this function 1000+(!!) times. 
What am I doing wrong? (See the console logs for the amount of executions)

[Plunkr of doom](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Z2XRVhyyGQeaPdFtVna?p=preview)

Edit: I also tried adding/removing `null` options. This causes weird execution times as well.

- `null` prefilled list with no `null` option -> `compareWith` executed 1200+ times.
- `null` prefilled list with `null` option -> `compareWith` executed 50 times ( as it should).
- initialised list with no `null` option: executed 1000+ times
- initialised list with `null` option: executed 1000+ times

[Plunkr2](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gv6dM4XuRKOsz5Cbu9WX)

Comment: By giving him a reference: `selectB: [this.list[0]]` it only got executed 100 times. You only need the compare function if it is not a reference. Sure you can't pass a ref?

Comment: In my real usecase, my list is comming from the backend, and I prefill the formcontrol with a value i have in some object. So the identities are not the same. I only can pass a reference if i prefill my formcontrol with the corresponding object in the list, and then i don't need to use compareWith at all. But then i still don't know why compareWith is giving so many iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged this for a while and came to a conclusion :) One clue was the following statement from the **[link](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)** you shared. That is, that with `compareWith`...

> We listen to the `change` event

So let's try and explain this behavior with your `C` option with object. `compareWith` is fired each time change happen, so naturally it will be fired when the array is modified. So it will be fired every time an item is "added" to your array on initialization:

***// change happened in array***

compare `obj1` with our form control

***// change happened in array***

compare `obj1`, compare `obj2` with form control

***// change happened in array***

compare `obj1`, compare `obj2`, compare `obj3` with form control

and so it continues until we hit a match. The above would be without the `null` option you have in your select. But since you also have the `[ngValue]="null"` to compare with, this would be what is compared to our form control:

```
null, null, 01, null, 01, 02, null, 01, 02, 03, null ....
```

and so on..

So when each item will be added, the iteration of comparing will start all over again from the first item to the most latest added item.

As for why the two other only executes 50 times, is because, `compareWith` is fired 50 times, since list changes 50 times, but in this case, when `compareWith` is run it hits a match everytime because it's comparing `null` to `null`, where other is form control value and other is the `null` option value.

---

As to your other question, you don't need to use `[compareWith]`, you can also just create a reference in another way. You mentioned in comment that you don't have an initial value to set when building the form, but when that object is available you can create a reference like:

```
this.form.patchValue({selectC: this.list.find(x => x.code == this.myObj.code)})
```

Now we do not need to worry about the amount of executions of `compareWith` :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This behaviour causes serious performance issues though, and I wonder why i would ever use compareWith then.

Comment: Yeah, this can be pretty costly! I debugged this with also using `ngModel`. If you have the `null` option it will run 80 times, since ngModel binding is initially `null`, so it's comparing `null` with `null` (50 times) and then 30 times to find match, so that is perfect! BUT, if you do not have the `null` option in dropdown, it actually executes 1275 times (in chrome)